# After we upgrade elastisearch-1.5.2 we are getting java.io.EOFException

Tags: elasticsearch

- After upgrade elasticsearch to 1.5.2 we are repeatedly getting:

> java.io.EOFException: read past EOF:
>   MMapIndexInput(path="/iqs/ESData/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/ids_1/1/index/segments_7")

- If we restart the cluster also the same exception is coming continuously. So we have one option left to delete the corrupted segment. But it's not the correct solution to our busy cluster. Can anyone suggest please.

Comment: are you using the recommended version of [jvm](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions/matrix)? also are they same version on all nodes ?

Comment: @keety we are using recommended version of jvm and also the same version for every nodes.